# Auto play video when hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment

I am trying to create a **music website**.

But I have stuck in a situation where I need to show my viewers what this music video contains (Basically a **5sec** video) when they hover over the `thumbnail`.

The size of the video(height and width) should be equal to the size of the `thumbnail`.

This is my code

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h5 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.center {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* End Non-Essential  */

.property-card {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 18em;
  width: 14em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 27px #e1e1e3, -15px -15px 27px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 27px #e1e1e3, -15px -15px 27px #ffffff;
}

/* ^-- The margin bottom is necessary for the drop shadow otherwise it gets clipped in certain cases. */

/* Top Half of card, image. */

.property-image {
  height: 15em;
  width: 14em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  position: Absolute;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  background-image: url('https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/What-is-landscape-photography.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Bottom Card Section */

.property-description {
  background-color: #FAFAFC;
  height: 5em;
  width: 14em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Social Icons */

.property-social-icons {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

/* Property Cards Hover States */

.property-card:hover .property-description {
  height: 0em;
  padding: 0px 1em;
}

.property-card:hover .property-image {
  height: 18em;

}

.property-card:hover .property-social-icons {
  background-color: white;
}

.property-card:hover .property-social-icons:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Relax</h1>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="property-card">
          <a href="#">
              <div class="property-image">
                  <div class="property-image-title"></div>
              </div>
          </a>
          <div class="property-description">
            <h5> Card Title </h5>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where's your video and script for playing video? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't know why snippet is not working. I was working when I uploaded the question.

Comment: Check again, your js script is not present

Comment: It's was an offline video in my hardick. So i removed that code because it will show an error in the code while I upload it in the snippet.

Comment: There is no javascript in my code until now

Comment: Then, put the video element without the source in your html so that it's clear which element to work on

Comment: Actually, the image should change into video. Like we do on youtube when we hover on the thumbnail it shows us a short video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the video element and hide it. Add `onmouseover` event listener to your image and play the video for 5 seconds when they hover over the image and display the image back after 5 seconds video preview.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video')
var image = document.getElementById('image')

image.onmouseover = function() {
  video.style.display = 'block'
  image.style.display = 'none'
  video.play()
  setTimeout(function() {
        video.pause()
        video.currentTime = 0
        video.style.display = 'none'
        image.style.display = 'block'
  }, 5000)
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h5 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.center {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* End Non-Essential  */

#video {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 18em;
  width: 14em;
  display: none;
  object-fit: cover
}

.property-card {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 18em;
  width: 14em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 27px #e1e1e3, -15px -15px 27px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 27px #e1e1e3, -15px -15px 27px #ffffff;
}

/* ^-- The margin bottom is necessary for the drop shadow otherwise it gets clipped in certain cases. */

/* Top Half of card, image. */

.property-image {
  height: 15em;
  width: 14em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  position: Absolute;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  background-image: url('https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/What-is-landscape-photography.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Bottom Card Section */

.property-description {
  background-color: #FAFAFC;
  height: 5em;
  width: 14em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Social Icons */

.property-social-icons {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

/* Property Cards Hover States */

.property-card:hover .property-description {
  height: 0em;
  padding: 0px 1em;
}

.property-card:hover .property-image {
  height: 18em;

}

.property-card:hover .property-social-icons {
  background-color: white;
}

.property-card:hover .property-social-icons:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Relax</h1>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="property-card">
          <a href="#">
              <div class="property-image" id="image">
                  <div class="property-image-title"></div>
              </div>
              <video id="video">
                <source control src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm"
                        type="video/webm">
            </video>
          </a>
          <div class="property-description">
            <h5> Card Title </h5>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `poster` attribute on your `video` for a placeholder image. Then you just need to add an event listener for users hovering in and out of your element. There doesn't appear to be anything related to a video in your code so I've put an example below:

Your HTML:

```
<div class="video-container">
<video id="my_video" controls poster="/path/to/image.jpg"> <!-- put your image here -->
  <source src="/path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <!-- path to your video here -->
</video>
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
.video-container {
width:500px;
height:300px;
}

video {
width:100%;
height:100%;
object-fit:cover;
}
```

`object-fit` will make your video's dimensions expand to fill its container.

Finally your JS:

```
let myVideo = document.getElementById("my_video");

myVideo.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    this.play();
});

myVideo.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    this.pause();
});
```